# Package documentation - RStudio, roxygen, devtools

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2, r-package

I am confused. I was used to the following flow when creating packages:

- create new package in RStudio using gui (named e.g. `testPackage`
- modify some files (let's say `DESCRIPTION` for beginning)
- write:

-

```
library(devtools)
document()
check()
load_all()
```

But now, for some reason `document()` does not propagate changes in `DESCRIPTION` to `testPackage-package.Rd` in `man` folder anymore. I get the following when using `document()`:

```
> document()
Updating testPackage documentation
Loading testPackage
First time using roxygen2 4.0. Upgrading automatically...
```

When I run `check()` I see in one of the lines:

Warning:

`...r/packages/testPackage.Rcheck/00_pkg_src/testPackage/man/testPackage-package.Rd:32: All text must be in a section`

Unfortunately, there is no additional information in `00install.out` as indiciated by `check()`. I am on Windows, R 3.1.2, RStudio 0.98.1091, devtools 1.7.0, roxygen2 4.1.0.

Did the process change or I have some inconsistent set of packages installed?

Comment: First time for me, same thing happening. Did you ever determine the cause?

Comment: I suspect you can safely delete **man/testPackage-package.Rd** and instead generate a **man/testPackage.Rd** with a **R/testPackage.R** file that documents `NULL` [with Roxygen](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html).